# Dynamic link to same entry but in alternate language

Tags: localization, plugin-seomatic

I'm working on a multilingual website (Spanish and English, default is Spanish). I'm using the SEOmatic plugin, and I see that it generates this code:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://localhost:8888/cmml/contacto" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://localhost:8888/cmml/en/contact-us" />
```

And I'm wondering if, instead of linking to the home page in an alternate language is there a way to link to the same resource in the alternate language?

Is there an *easy* way to achieve this? Thanks folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both SEOmatic for Craft 2 and SEOmatic for Craft 3 have built-in functions to give you these URLs. I'm not sure which you are using so...

For Craft 2: https://github.com/nystudio107/seomatic/wiki/15.-Utility-Filters-&-Functions#getlocalizedurls

For Craft 3: https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-seomatic#helper-functions-seomatichelper